How to populate Configuration Attribute value to Product Option on Configurator
I'm trying to have a Price Rule update a Product Option field based on that value populated and be visible in the Configurator.
I've create a configuration attribute with a value that will match the Price Condition above, I've ticked the "Apply Immediately" to Product Option, however, I can't seem to see that value being populated on the Configurator. So my question is, is it possible to populate a field on the Product Option in the configurator based on a value user enters in the Configuration Attribute?



Unfortunately, the configuration attribute isn’t visible on the user product selection screen until the Save button is clicked on the configuration screen. This is standard behavior.
After saving the configuration, the selected configuration attribute value will appear in the corresponding field on all the quote lines within the Quote Line Editor—provided the matching field exists on the quote line object and has been included in the relevant field set.
